# webservice error 500 Internal Error asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have written a webservice call in JQuery in document ready function but its not calling the function

Below is the code 
JQuery

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
var section = "Table - TLI (STOCK)";
$.ajax({
type: "GET",contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "pgWebService.aspx/SliderBlock",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{'section':'" + section + "'}",
        success: function (res) {
            //$("#Text1").val(res.text);
            console.log(res);
            alert("DONE");
        }
    });
});
</script>`
```

C# Code
pgWebService

```
public static string SliderBlock(string section)
{
    string html = "<ul class='maketabs listing-table search-filter change-view'>";
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TLI"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from CategoryDetails where section=" + section;
    SqlDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rs.Read())
    {
        html="<li>"+rs.getValue(0).toString()+"</li>";
    }
    rs.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    cn.Close();
    html = html + "</ul>";
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Is it in code behind or in separate webserivce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your method `SliderBlock` is in code behind than make your method `WebMethod` to be called by ajax.Also you need to make it `static` and to be called by `GET` you need to `enable GET` requests on your WebMethod.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string SliderBlock(string section)
{
//Your code here
}
```

Comment: @naveen thnks.Updated it,

Comment: @MairajAhmad got the point and i made the necessary changes but still its giving me 500 Internal Error

Comment: Can u check in browser console to see the detailed error and post it here.

Comment: i have a different page in which i am calling the webservice and the pgWebservice.aspx page is different the error in console is as below:GET 
http://localhost:1312/PMS/pgWebService.aspx/SliderBlock [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 27ms]

Comment: Yes click the link in console to see details.

Answer (score 0):

As your code has the extension `.aspx` I assume that you are using the code-behind ( Page Method ). So you need to make these changes to your function signature

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SliderBlock(string section)
```

That is,

1. your method should be static.
2. your method should be decorated with `System.Web.Services.WebMethod`

And in your $.ajax call, change the dataType to json.

```
dataType: "json"
```

Also, please bear in mind that the PageMethid in pgWebService.aspx.cs *can be only called from* pgWebService.aspx

Comment: how can i call a text changed event of the textbox from a webmethod??

Answer (score 0):

You still have errors in the ajax request:

**Content-Type**: When sending data to the server, use this content type. But you are not sending data to the server except the query string parameters because you are doing a GET. So, if you inspect with webbrowser developer tools the request you see a GET with this URL: *localhost/pgWebService.aspx/SliderBlock?section=selectedSection* because...

**Data**: Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.

**dataType**: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. But in your webService your are returning a string with HTML not JSON.

Comment: can u give some example on it